# Where does apt download kernel debugging symbols from?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

Long story short: I need debugging symbols of various kernel versions for scientific purposes. (Memory forensics)

I followed some [guide](https://hadibrais.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/installing-ubuntu-kernel-debugging-symbols/) which lead me to executing:

```
$ apt-get install  --print-uris linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 284 not upgraded.
Need to get 15,4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22,5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux-signed/linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym_5.4.0-58.64_amd64.ddeb' linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym_5.4.0-58.64_amd64.ddeb 15420 MD5Sum:abf99aad97774011358418df34d0c5f1
```

On my Ubuntu machine.
And voilá: I got `/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.4.0-58-generic` on that machine.

However: When I directly download the url that `apt-get` printed there due to `--print-uris`, the deb file does not contain the debugging symbol file! I was hoping that I would find debugging symbols there AND debugging symbols for different version in the same [folder](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux-signed/). But it seems like none of them contain the actual dwarf file.

Any help would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the package in question comes with dependencies:

```
# LANG=C dpkg -i linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym_5.4.0-58.64_amd64.ddeb 
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym.
(Reading database ... 473483 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym_5.4.0-58.64_amd64.ddeb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym (5.4.0-58.64) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym:
 linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym depends on linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym; however:
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-58-generic-dbgsym is not installed.
[...]
```

You want to install the latter as well.

Comment: That actually led me to the right place! For the next guy, they are stored here: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/